# Android memory leak? Navigation SDK not working properly

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks

I'm using a navigation SDK to get turn-by-turn directions in an Android app -- but the SDK is not performing properly.

When I start navigation, memory usage in the app starts to rise and fall. It looks like this (from Android Monitor in Android Studio):

[image]

I'm concerned there may be a memory leak problem that is causing navigation to not work properly.

**Does the memory graph above look normal? Or does it look like I have a memory leak? Any other insights?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the graph shows that there is a memory leak in your app  and

you can request to use more by using android:largeHeap="true" in the manifest.

You can also use a library LeakCanary which is used for catching memory leaks in your apps.